# Skip certain columns "fields" with mysqldump

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to restrict certain columns "fields" from the mysqldump command?

E.g. I want to dump profile database which has 2 tables "table 1, table 2". in table 1 there is column "field" name first_name and in table 2 there is column "field" name address and column "field" name last name which I want to skip.

Comment: Duplicate question, see this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/mysqldump-tables-excluding-some-fields#answer-34889

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort or you could answer and say "No" for my upvote

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort it is not duplicate, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/mysqldump-tables-excluding-some-fields#answer-34889 is about dumping a single table, while my question is about dumping the whole database.

Comment: The answer is no you can't. Unless you tweak the source code and recompile it